# debugger won't install Rails 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I was trying to do a `bundle update` and I got:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1573:in
>   `stat': No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat -
>   ./212/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)    from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1573:in`
>   block in fu_each_src_dest'   from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1587:in
>   `fu_each_src_dest0'   from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in`
>   fu_each_src_dest'    from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:399:in
>   `cp'  from extconf.rb:83:in`block in '     from extconf.rb:82:in
>   `each'    from extconf.rb:82:in`'
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

So I tried to do the following: `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` and got

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing debugger:  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1573:in
>   `stat': No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat -
>   ./212/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)    from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1573:in`
>   block in fu_each_src_dest'   from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1587:in
>   `fu_each_src_dest0'   from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in`
>   fu_each_src_dest'    from
>   /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:399:in
>   `cp'  from extconf.rb:83:in`block in '     from extconf.rb:82:in
>   `each'    from extconf.rb:82:in`'
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out

I have 4 other rails apps all running 4.1.5 and they all have no issue with `bundle update` so what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The debugger gem isn't supposed to be used with `ruby 2.0+`, and literally won't install with `ruby 2.1.2`.  You are going to have to switch to [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

If you're a fan of pry there is also [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug)

Here is how my debugging gems in my Gemfile look like with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.2

```
group :development do
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry-remote'
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
    gem 'pry-byebug'
end
```